# The right way to use aliases in SQL

Tags: sql

I have question about SQL. Below I have query from order controller in Prestashop 1.6. The question is. Why I have two aliases for ps_orders ? Please check below query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
       a.`id_order`,
       `reference`,
       `total_paid_tax_incl`,
       `payment`,
       a.`date_add` AS `date_add`,
       a.id_currency,
       a.id_order AS id_pdf,
       CONCAT(LEFT(c.`firstname`, 1), '. ', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`,
       osl.`name` AS `osname`,
       os.`color`,
       IF(
            (SELECT COUNT(id_customer)
             FROM `ps_orders` so
             WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer) = 1, "Tak", "Nie") AS first_order,
       IF(
            (SELECT so.id_order
             FROM `ps_orders` so
             WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer
               AND so.id_order < a.id_order
             LIMIT 1) > 0, 0, 1) AS NEW,
       country_lang.name AS cname,
       IF(a.valid, 1, 0) badge_success
FROM `ps_orders` a
LEFT JOIN `ps_customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`)
LEFT JOIN `ps_address` address ON address.id_address = a.id_address_delivery
LEFT JOIN `ps_country` country ON address.id_country = country.id_country
LEFT JOIN `ps_country_lang` country_lang ON (country.`id_country` = country_lang.`id_country`
                                             AND country_lang.`id_lang` = 6)
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_state` os ON (os.`id_order_state` = a.`current_state`)
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state`
                                        AND osl.`id_lang` = 6)
WHERE 1
ORDER BY a.`id_order` DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Once I have `a.id_order` in another `so.id_order`. Maybe I am wrong but I thing that is the same ps_orders. First declaration is `ps_orders so` and the second `ps_orders a` ? Why someone use two aliases to the same table ?

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: `ps_orders` is used three times in the query so each time (to distinguish them, duh!) there is a different alias used.

Comment: You have two aliases because you have two different _subqueries_.  What is your actual question?  Does this query run?

Comment: Syntax suggests MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General queries are like:

```
SELECT
    A.SomeColumn
FROM
    YourTable A
```

If you have **subqueries** then

```
SELECT
    A.SomeColumn,
    (SELECT SomeOtherColumn FROM AnotherTable) ColumnAlias
FROM
    YourTable A
```

And if you have a subquery with **the same table**, you might want to use different aliases to distinguish them!

```
SELECT
    A.SomeColumn,
    (SELECT B.SomeColumn FROM YourTable B) ColumnAlias
FROM
    YourTable A
```

Columns from tables referenced in subqueries **cannot** be referenced outside:

```
SELECT
    A.SomeColumn,
    (SELECT B.SomeOtherColumn FROM YourTable B) ColumnAlias,
    B.SomeOtherColumn -- What table is B here? Outside scope!
FROM
    YourTable A
```

But columns from the outside **can** be referenced inside!

```
SELECT
    A.SomeColumn,
    (SELECT B.SomeOtherColumn FROM YourTable B WHERE B.SomeOtherColumn = A.SomeColumn) ColumnAlias,
FROM
    YourTable A
```

PD: I'm assuming in these examples that the subquery returns 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

One alias is for the main query, and the other is used in the sub queries.

The main query and each subquery must use an alias since they both are referencing the same table as the main query.

That's the only way the sub query can relate to the records from the same table used in the main query - Just like when you do a self join - Once you have the same table (or view) more than once in your query, you must use different aliases for it.